# Adding Manual prop to react-table disables internal sort and filter

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Adding manual prop to react-table disables internal sort and filter functionality in react-table 6.8.6 version. 
How do I handle this to have filter and sort internally with server-side pagination ?

```
<ReactTable 
  manual 
  filterable={true} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set manual in ReactTable, it indicates that you are handling sorting, filtering feature on server side. In that case, you must use the following callbacks.  [More detail, check here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-v6#server-side-data)

```
  onPageChange={(pageIndex) => {...}} 
  onPageSizeChange={(pageSize, pageIndex) => {...}}
  onSortedChange={(newSorted, column, shiftKey) => {...}} 
  onFilteredChange={(column, value) => {...}}
```

You can check this sandbox for an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8297r0j8p2?file=/src/useContactsTable.js)